# Как правильно преобразовать дату в миллисекунды?

Tags: java, android, дата, datetime

Есть строковая переменная даты "2015-06-18T14:10:15.945158Z". Хочу перевести в миллисекунды. Эту задачу выполняю таким образом:

```
    String date = "2015-06-18T14:10:15.945158Z";

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
        Date date1 =  simpleDateFormat.parse(date);

        Log.i("parse date :", date1.getTime() + "");

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

И проблема заключается в том, что переводит не точно. При проверке (то есть при обратном преобразовании) время выводит с разницей 5-15 мин. Например: должно вывести 14:10, а вывело 14:26. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: А как обратно переводишь?

Comment: либо через класс Calendar, либо через он лайн сервисы

Comment: Я посмотрел. У тебя парсер date1 уже делает неправильный

Comment: Если миллисекунды не принципиальны, можешь их не парсить SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

Comment: Вообще у тебя странные входные данные о миллисекундах и тайм зоне. Посмотри тут http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: не хватает перевода преобразования в обратную сторону

Comment: По поводу странности входных данных, то просто такой ответ от сервера, и с этим ничего поделать не могу.

Comment: Спасибо пользователю - Алексей Мальченко - помог вариант без парсинга миллисекунд.

Answer (score 1):

Если во входной дате оставить только 3 знака миллисекунд, как в формате, вместо 6, то все корректно отработает. (т.е. микросекундами придется пожертвовать).

Кстати таймзона в getTime не учитывается, возвращается время в миллисекундах с 1900 года именно в UTC таймзоне.

Comment: Похоже, у авторов парсера была потрясающая логика, как работать с миллисекундами...

Comment: Может просто они предполагали что миллисекунды будут целым числом, а про микросекунды никто ничего не обещал :)

Comment: Там немного не так, судя по вопросу. Как будто бы он берёт число 945158 как миллисекунды, что примерно 945 секунд или 15 минут. И вопрос, почему отклонение на 15 минут. Потому что милисекунды переполнились. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Кстати да, @Qwertiy ты судя по всему прав, именно поэтому смещение происходило, т.е. парсит он нормально, но считает это миллисекундами а не микросекундами, поэтому прибавляет 15 минут.